# Incorrect range input state persists after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on my range input component, but I don't understand what's wrong (img 4).

After refreshing the page, it does not reset the results, but saves them incorrectly, not displaying the progress, or vice versa filling it all (the second input), what could be the problem?

On local server:
[image: range]

On local server after page refresh:
[image: range]

In production:
[image: range]

❗️ In production after page refresh:
[image: range]

Why is he doing this? Nothing is stored in the local storage.

The code (top range input):

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function Slider({ min, max, onChange }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const minValRef = useRef(min);
  const range = useRef(null);

  // Convert to percentage
  const getPercent = useCallback(
    (value) => Math.round(((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100),
    [value]
  );

  // Set width of the range to decrease from the left side
  useEffect(() => {
    const maxPercent = getPercent(value);
    const minPercent = getPercent(minValRef.current);

    if (range.current) {
      range.current.style.width = `${maxPercent - minPercent}%`;
    }
  }, [value, getPercent]);

  // Get values when their state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange({ min: value });
  }, [value, onChange]);

  //Tooltips
  useEffect(() => {
    const range = document.getElementById("range");
    const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");

    let thumbSize = 10;
    const ratio = (range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min);
    let amountToMove =
      ratio * (range.offsetWidth - thumbSize - thumbSize) + thumbSize;
    tooltip.style.left = amountToMove + "px";
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative flex h-[24px] w-full items-center">
        <input
          className="relative flex h-[6px] w-full appearance-none rounded-full bg-blue-100 dark:bg-gray-700"
          aria-valuemin={0}
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="100"
          value={value}
          id="range"
          onChange={({ target: { value: radius } }) => {
            setValue(radius);
          }}
        />

        <div
          ref={range}
          className="absolute top-[9px] z-10 h-[6px] w-1 rounded-full bg-blue-400"
        />

        <div
          id="tooltip"
          className={`${
            value > 0 ? "visible" : "invisible"
          } absolute top-[-40px] flex h-[32px] w-[32px] -translate-x-1/2 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-gray-700 align-middle text-body-small text-white`}
        >
          <div className="absolute bottom-[-5px] flex">
            <div className="border-l-[10px] border-t-[8.5px] border-r-[10px] border-l-transparent border-t-gray-700 border-r-transparent"></div>
          </div>
          {value}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Slider };
```

Comment: Why do you use `document.getElementById` with react?

Comment: I'm new to react, useId is more correct? Or something else? Could this be an error?

Comment: You should use `style` prop for styling

Comment: I use Tailwind for styling, if I style the div do you think the errors will go away? I'll try, thanks

Comment: Doesn't help, I add style props to the div, but the error didn't go away
<div
          ref={range}
          // className="absolute top-[9px] z-10 h-[6px] w-1 rounded-full bg-blue-400"
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: "9px",
            zIndex: 10,
            height: "6px",
            width: 1,
            backgroundColor: "red",
          }}
        />

Comment: Friend, your tailwind styles were fine. The problem could be the first and the third `useEffect` because you are modifying the dom directly

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll think about it. And why then everything works as it should on the local server, but not in the prod?